# Embed video clips into app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, video

I need to embed small video clips into an app I am making. Something along the lines of what the moov app or the sworkit app does. They have small workout clips in the upper portion of the view, which seem more like gifs. This is my first time trying something like this. I would like to know what approach I should take. Should I upload some clips and stream it from a url or should I add video content into my app itself? I don't want the app to become to heavy but at the same time I don't want to compromise on the user experience. How should i go about doing this? What considerations should i take into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for the Swift aspect, but Sworkit uses very short video clips and loops them to keep app size down. If you need more videos which will be used over and over again or without a connection, download them and the play them in a similar loop fashion.

Your main consideration here should be experience. Do you want them to wait for a download? Do you want to require them to be online? Those will help you with most of that decision process. An 8 second video for Sworkit that comes on the device is about 200kb

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of application. For example a gym application you may want to include the video asset inside the application and load the resource from there since it may be an essential part of using the application and the user may not have an internet connection.

If the video is not an essential part of the application or maybe an optional tutorial then you could stream it from a url since it won't matter as much if the video buffers or can't be played.

Just remember to take the user experience into consideration when making a choice like this inside your application.